# Reuse of computed Constant Values in Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have encountered the following behavior and I'm not quite sure if this is a bug or if I'm missing out on something.

### Minimal Example

```
# Create constant Matrix A
A1 = tf.convert_to_tensor(A, dtype=tf.float64)

# Compute the cholesky decomposition
sqrtA1 = tf.linalg.cholesky(tfA1)

xi = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=[10000])

# Matrix multiplication with the chompsky matrix
RessqrtA1 = tf.tensordot(tfsqrtA1, tfxi, [[1],[0]])

# Regular Matrix multiplication
ResA1 = tf.tensordot(tfA1, tfxi, [[1],[0]])
```

Upon Computing something like this:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    _ = sess.run(ResA1, feed_dict={xi: np.random.randn(10000)})
    _ = sess.run(ResA1, feed_dict={xi: np.random.randn(10000)})
```

One could assume that the first `sess.run()` will take more time since the Graph has to be build and optimized. And that is what happens, here are some timings just like expected:

```
normal matmul
Wall time: 36.1 s -- first run 

41.1 ms ± 2.15 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each) 
--second run with timit
```

### Long Calculation times despite a constant Operation

Now one might think that the same holds when multiplying the `sqrtA1`, but **unfortunately its not**.
Computing the following:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    _ = sess.run(RessqrtA1, feed_dict={xi: np.random.randn(10000)})
    _ = sess.run(RessqrtA1, feed_dict={xi: np.random.randn(10000)})
```

Here are some timings:

```
cholesky
Wall time: 2min 38s
24.7 s ± 750 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

I ran the TensorFlow Profiler and obtained this information:

```
Profile:
node name | requested bytes | total execution time | accelerator execution time | cpu execution time
Cholesky                     800.00MB (100.00%, 50.00%),     24.30sec (100.00%, 99.81%),             0us (0.00%, 0.00%),     24.30sec (100.00%, 99.81%)
MatMul                          80.00KB (50.00%, 0.00%),         46.45ms (0.19%, 0.19%),             0us (0.00%, 0.00%),         46.45ms (0.19%, 0.19%)
Reshape                               0B (0.00%, 0.00%),            15us (0.00%, 0.00%),             0us (0.00%, 0.00%),            15us (0.00%, 0.00%)
Const                         800.00MB (50.00%, 50.00%),            10us (0.00%, 0.00%),             0us (0.00%, 0.00%),            10us (0.00%, 0.00%)
```

### Difference between TF 1.7 and TF 1.6

Now for the **interesting Part**: This is **only** when you use **Version 1.7.0 or higher**
I tried this with Version 1.6.0 and the Matmuls with the cholesky matrix took not longer than a normal matmul:

```
Wall time: 1min 18s -- first run
49.7 ms ± 1.02 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
-- timeit on the second sess.run()
```

When looking into the Computation in Version 1.6 with the Profiler you get:

```
Profile:node name | requested bytes | total execution time | accelerator execution time | cpu execution time
Cholesky                    800.00MB (100.00%, 100.00%),       891us (100.00%, 100.00%),             0us (0.00%, 0.00%),       891us (100.00%, 100.00%)
======================End of Report==========================
```

Lastely, using this code, while replacing `RessqrtA1 = tf.tensordot(chol, tfxi, [[1],[0]])`,where `chol` is another **Placeholder**, gives us the desired outcome again.

```
%time temp = sess.run(tfsqrtA1)
%timeit _ = sess.run(tfRessqrtA1, feed_dict={tfxi: np.random.randn(10000), chol: temp})

cholesky
Wall time: 1min 40s
42.6 ms ± 3.86 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

### My Thoughts:

Somehow since Version 1.7 for every session run the cholesky calculation happens despite being from constant origin and thus it would suffice to calculate it once and reuse the outcome.

I think that such a computation happens in version 1.6 during the construction of the Graph as I measured that the **calculation of the Cholesky Decomposition** takes about **26sec in V1.6** (used a Placeholder so that it needs to be calculated during runtime), yet during the run it only took 900us as shown above.

In v1.7 they somehow changed this behavior.

### The Question

Do you think this behavior change is normal or desired? If so, what would be a better approach when you have a similar situation?

I'm thankful for every information, maybe someone else noticed some related problems using the linear algebra class.

### What i have tried so far:

- tinkering around with the float size (i.e. `tf.float32` instead of `tf.float64`)
- used different Versions in seperate environments.
- used the profiler to investigate the times of different Ops
- ran on a different pc
- timing in Python (e.g. `timeit` or `pycallgraph`)